# How to automatically document the image dimensions of a huge list of different sized images?

Tags: images, automation, batch-processing, measurement, multiple-sizes

I have over 1000 images to process and it would make life easier if I could obtain the dimensions of the each image in a spreadsheet or document.

I was hoping for a program or something where I could drag and drop the images to the program and it automatically created a CSV (Comma Separated Values list) of dimensions.

How can I automatically generate a list of image dimensions from a folder with over 1000 images in it?

Comment: The metadata fields are known yes so not really a problem. What operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved with easy via simple php script:

1. You upload all images to a folder on server
2. Use `scandir` for get array of urls (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
3. Do a iterative `foreach` for your array with urls (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
4. Get image sizes of each with `getimagesize` (http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php)
5. Format as you like and output to your HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which platform you're on, but I know it's quite easy on Ubuntu using the package 'libimage-exiftool-perl'

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

For example, to extract height & width from JPG files only in a particular folder and export the results to csv, you could run:

```
exiftool -csv -ext jpg -ImageWidth -ImageHeight /MyFolder > output.csv
```

It's a very powerful tool that can do much more than this, more info [HERE](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

EDIT: There are Windows and OSX builds available on the page link above as well, I haven't used them.